# unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Volunteers WHERE Volunteers.eventID = " . $var);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Members.pid = " . $temp);
```

I am also doing or die(mysql_error()) at the end of both statements if that matter. My problem is that the first statement executes perfectly but in that table I store an attribute called pid. So the second statement is supposed to take that and return the row where it equals that pid so I can get the name. I get an error that says unknown column in 'a2' in 'where clause' where a2 the pid attribute returned from the first statement. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Figured out what was wrong. 
Had to write the code like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Members.pid = '$temp'") or   die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: IT may help if you provide more code, you are not telling us where you get this value for $temp. It is probably to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do, you can do this in one query, by JOIN-ing the tables together. the SQL query should be something like

```
SELECT Members.* FROM Members INNER JOIN Volunteers ON Volunteers.eventID=Members.pid WHERE Volunteers.eventID=" . $var
```

Check out [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for a basic introduction to SQL joins.