# Unknown column in WHERE clause when using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I have a query like the below:

```sql
SELECT *, (
    SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=``.``
) AS `fullName` FROM `listings` WHERE `fullName` LIKE '%praveen%';
```

But when I execute the above query, I am getting this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'fullName' in 'where clause'
```

I know that this bug has been [documented](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28814). I am not sure what's the workaround for this other than doing something like:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=`listings`.`user`
) FROM `listings` WHERE (SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE users`.`id`=`listings`.`user`) LIKE '%praveen%';
```

Is there any other way I can do this other than creating a view, or using a query like the above? I have tried referring other questions:

- [Unknown column in subquery where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941770/unknown-column-in-subquery-where-clause)
- [Unknown column when using subquery result column in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664991/unknown-column-when-using-subquery-result-column-in-where-clause)
- [Unknown Column In Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause)
- [Unknown column '' in 'where clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042998/unknown-column-in-where-clause)
- [unknown column in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635445/unknown-column-in-where-clause)

I couldn't find a better solution. What's the best can I do in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct syntax of what you are after:

```
select l.*, u.name as fullname
  from listings l
  join users u
    on l.user = u.id
 where u.name like '%praveen%'
```

Comment: It should be faster; there is no reason for you to have a subquery in the SELECT list in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (
    SELECT *
        , (SELECT `name` 
           FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=``.``
           ) AS `fullName` 
    FROM `listings` 
   ) Q
WHERE `Q`.`fullName` LIKE '%praveen%';
```

Comment: This looks like triple subquery!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable:

```
SELECT *, @var_fullName := (
    SELECT `name` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `users`.`id`=``.``
) AS `fullName` 
FROM `listings` 
WHERE @var_fullName LIKE '%praveen%';
```